# How to code floating boxes for mobile screens

Tags: mobile, responsive-design, screen, floating, box

I´m trying to do the following on a website. I guess it´s quite simple for thoose who have programmed alot but for me it´s new. Can someone show me how to code this? Thanks!

Layout on computer screen and mobile screen
[image]

Comment: Simplest option (which will likely get downvoted hence a comment) - set your divs to float left:  `<div style='float:left;padding-right:0.5em;'>`   Or you can use 'bootstrap-twitter' for a complete responsive-design framework.

Comment: What I´m looking for is the code (html and css) for media screens so the boxes change their positions autmaticly on different devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use media queries to make your HTML and CSS code produce different results in user's browser on different devices.

Media queries usually based on `max-width` of the browser viewport.

So, if browser viewport will be less than 800px wide, additional styles will be applied.

```css
.box
{
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 10px;
  width: 180px;
  height: 180px;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  background: #DDD;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px)
{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
```

**For iPads & iPhones**

If you need to have different layouts on iPads and iPhones, you need to take proper media queries from this article: http://stephen.io/mediaqueries/.
You have to write specific CSS rules for each device you'd like to support in particular.

---

Layout examples:

> [image: Desktop layout]

**Desktop layout**

> [image: Tablet layout]

**Tablet layout**

> [image: Phone layout]

**Phone layout**

(Pictures are from [w3schools.com](http://w3schools.com))

> About media queries:
>
> 1. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries
> 2. http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp
> 3. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

Comment: Thanks Vladimir! Your code works fine on my computer browser and the boxes change postition like they should when I change size on the browser window. But when I try the web page on my iPhone 5 it won´t work. The boxes are still in horizontal position. Is there something missing in the code?

Comment: I'm not very sure, but I know that some iPhones has Retina display that doubles pixels density. So, screen width could be more than `800px` even it's mobile. http://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/iphone-6-screens-demystified. I've updated my answer to cover iPhone usecases.